# Adding labels to a 3D pie chart in D3.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'm trying to recreate the 3D pie chart in this example: http://bl.ocks.org/NPashaP/9994181

Here's my version: http://jsfiddle.net/26v6cc8x/1/

```
var salesData=[
    {label:"Basic", color:"#3366CC"},
    {label:"Plus", color:"#DC3912"},
    {label:"Lite", color:"#FF9900"},
    {label:"Elite", color:"#109618"},
    {label:"Delux", color:"#990099"}
];

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width",700).attr("height",400);

svg.append("g").attr("id","quotesDonut");

Donut3D.draw("quotesDonut", randomData(), 450, 150, 250, 150, 50, 0);

function changeData(){
    Donut3D.transition("quotesDonut", randomData(), 250, 150, 50, 0);
}

function randomData(){
    return salesData.map(function(d){ 
        return {label:d.label, value:1000*Math.random(), color:d.color};});
}

 $(".btn-change").click(function(){
        changeData();
 });
```

My question is, how do I add the actual data labels (not the calculated percentages) outside the pie and make sure they keep their correct position after transition? Meaning I want both percentages and labels to show up.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In the **Donut3D.js** change the following function:

```
function getPercent(d){
  return (d.endAngle-d.startAngle > 0.2 ? 
  Math.round(1000*(d.endAngle-d.startAngle) / (Math.PI * 2)) /10 + '%' : '');
}
```

To this:

```
function getPercent(d) {
  return (d.endAngle - d.startAngle > 0.2 ?
  d.data.label + ': ' + Math.round(1000 * (d.endAngle - d.startAngle) / (Math.PI * 2)) / 10 + '%' : '');}
```

This will prefix the label to the percentage value that shows in the graph.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Right, but I want the label to be added outside the pie around the edges of the pie, while keeping the percentages where they are which is inside the pie. does that make sense?

Comment: Why should we use random function in donut chart?

Comment: How to give dynamic values instead of random values?